# How to i use the variable from express in html?

Tags: html, node.js, express, nodejs-server

I have this in express

```
app.get('/', requiresAuth(), (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile('/db_auth_site/index.html', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
);
```

How can i use title in html like?

```
<h1>title variable here</h1>
```

Comment: Isn't the second argument to `sendFile` the [options object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't per se. HTML doesn't have that capability.

You need to use a template language such as [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/), or [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

The [Express documentation has a section that covers using Pug](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and  [MDN has a more detailed guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Template_primer).

Other template languages are similar, you just change the modules you install and the `view engine` setting then use the syntax of the template language you picked.

Note that most template languages are "The language you want to output with special tags inside" but Pug is very much an exception. If you want to write something that looks like HTML, don't use Pug.

You also need to use [`render`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) instead of `sendFile`.

Comment: Hay sendFile works tho so should i change to send?

Comment: @Rohit — It works when you want to send a file. It doesn't work when you want to inject data into a template and send the output.

Comment: ohh ok let me check the link you posted

Comment: And I meant `render`, not `send`.

Comment: oh ok i did send and it gave a error let me do render

Comment: Error: Module "html" does not provide a view engine.

Comment: @Rohit — Well yes. HTML isn't a template language. You need to pick one and set it up according to the documentation I linked to in paragraph three of this answer. The last line of this answer doesn't solve the problem by itself.

Comment: I tried using view engine and .pug file so it works but i cant use normal html?

Comment: HTML is not a template language, so no. However, see paragraph 5 of this answer.

Comment: hmm ok i will look into some other alternatives